# Asp.net Core 2 AddAuthorization causing 500 internal server error - problems in Startup

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a project which i have configured to use JWT for authentication. FOr authorization I want to use role based policies. All good so I make the changes to my Startup.cs.

I have in "ConfigureServices" the following added service.

```
// Use policy auth.
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("DisneyUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DisneyCharacter", "IAmMickey"));
  });
```

and this works when I go get a JWT token.

If I change it to

```
// Use policy auth.
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("DisneyUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DisneyCharacter", "IAmMickey"));
      options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
      options.AddPolicy("EmployeeAccess", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Employee"));
  });
```

its still works.

However if I removed the first policy line and I am left with:

```
// Use policy auth.
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
      options.AddPolicy("EmployeeAccess", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Employee"));
  });
```

I get the following status when I go get a JWT token..

500 Internal Server Error.

Wonder if anybody might have a clue as to why having these two options only breaks it?

Comment: You should provide the complete stack trace, 500 internal server error can mean a lot of things.

Comment: Based on the description, it is unlikely to do with the options. Instead, you might want to look at how your authorization is used in your application. It is likely expecting the `DisneyUser` to be setup.

Comment: An `[Authorize]` might be expecting for there to be a policy named DisneyCharacter. It being missing would certainly cause an exception, causing a 500 error.